# Android Emulator on will not launch on Windows 8

Tags: android-emulator

I've been running and testing my android app using my android device for a while now. Recently I've been trying to test it on various avds with various display sizes to make sure the layout is displayed correctly. I cannot get avd to launch. Once I create avd and click start then launch, 'starting android emulator' appears with progress bar moving as normal. Just before progress bar reaches 100% window closes. I wait for avd to open but nothing happens.

It's been a while since I used avd, but I remember it worked. Since I last used avd I have upgraded from Window7 to Windows8. I've looked all over for an answer with no luck. I don't know whether it is a problem with Windows8 or whether it is my system as I am using a HP Mini 110 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270 1.6GHz 2GB RAM 32 bit x86 based precessor. It's really annoying and it's stopping me from making progress.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was the low ram on your system. Try to have low ram on your avd. Also dont use native gpu on api under 15.